# Python: How to import modules that depends on other modules from another directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is my folder structure:

```
src
  file1.py
  file2.py
tests
  test1.py
```

```
#file1.py

from file2 import module2
modules = 'module1' + module2
```

```
#file2.py

module2 = 'module2'
```

```
#test1.py

import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from src.file1 import modules

print(modules)
```

I cannot "import modules from src.file1" because ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'.

How can I import modules from another folder where the module that I am importing also imports modules from other files?

Comment: I assume you have a folder `project` including `src` and `tests` and you use vscode to open `project` as a workspace.
Is it valid to change `sys.path.append('..')` to `sys.path.append("./")`?   Or use the absolute path of `project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the following launch config I have it running

```json
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File from src folder",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    }
```

and a change to `test1.py`

```py
import sys
try:
  # for editing
  sys.path.append('..')
  from src.file1 import modules
except ImportError:
  # for running
  sys.path.append('.')
  from file1 import modules

print(modules)
```

Answer (score 0):

put your directories (src and test) in a directory (path_problem)

change test1.py

```py
#test1.py
from src.file1 import modules
print(f"in {__file__} with {modules}")
```

create a file called init.py and another called run.py in the path_problem diectory

```py
#init.py
#create paths to all local directories

from pathlib import Path
import sys

here = Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.append(str(here))

for d in here.glob("*"):
    if d.is_dir():
        sys.path.append(str(d))
```

```py
# run.py
import init

from test1 import modules
```

```
run run.py
```

You should see the output of the print statement in test1.py